# Robotframework - tap, swipe and other "mobile" methods with hybrid app on Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, robotframework, hybrid-mobile-app

Can you help me with understanding and finding right way to start tests with using "mobile" methods (e.g. tap, swipe)?
I'm working with RF with ExtendedSelenium2Library, hybrid app (angularjs) is running with ionic. Simple tests with clicking elements are working properly. But what if I want to use tap or swipe (appium, ios library)? How to configure it? I've read many articles about it, but no idea how to start it up.

I will appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Selenum2Library supports a concept of actions.

You'll need to expose the inner selenium 2 library in your own package (I did that by extending the existing package and importing my extension instead - but you can also use a keyword that returns the internal library - there is one in selenium2library), and then you can create new keywords that adhere to the concept of actions.

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html

https://techblog.polteq.com/en/perform-a-sequence-of-actions-with-selenium-webdriver/